# How to deal with a schism in the party, relating to criminal activity?

Tags: group-dynamics, party, warhammer

Myself and 5 friends (one of whom is DM) are playing Warhammer.  Increasingly, 3 members want to engage in criminal activities like burglary and robbery, while myself and another party member are scrupulous, honest types, who refuse to turn into common criminals (this is from our character sheet backgrounds, not just our personal opinions).

What's a good way to reconcile this difference?  The way it's going at the moment, it won't be long before the 3 wannabe criminals just start leaving me and the other "good" guy alone to go off and burgle some noble's mansion.

We are all good friends in real life, and are "mature" (late 40s/early 50s), and we can all take a fair bit of ribbing, abuse, joking etc - I don't think anyone is close to storming out.  The problem really is that we spend a lot of each session arguing about what to do.

Comment: Ingame, what is keeping your team together?

Comment: Good question.  Not much I suppose - we teamed up to do a specific mission and it fell through.  After that we had another quest which ended in disaster, the reward turning out to be a ruse to draw my character (or actually the person he was impersonating) in and kill him.  After all that, we lack a clear single direction.

Comment: Is creating new characters an option, or are you and your friend really not interested in a game where you all role play a criminal gang?

Comment: Funnily enough I was thinking of changing my character class ("Career" in Warhammer), but literally the first line of my background is that I am "scrupulously honest" so even if I change class I feel like I should still be resistent to criminality.  Although, maybe going over to criminality is part of the character growth.

Comment: Even if I do though, that doesn't mean the other "good guy" will.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Have you had this Out of Character conversation with the other "good guy" yet?

Comment: I have not, he said, adding pointless characters to his comment to get past the limit.

Comment: Are you arguing in character or out of character?

Comment: @divibisan always in character, we've never had an out-of-game argument about it.  I don't think it would ever come to that, we're all quite respectful of each other in real life (joshing aside).  I think the key is to give our party some focus and we've been having some good discussions by email in between sessions about what that should be, and I think we've found a couple of shared goals to go after, one of which will probably lead us on to an actual quest proper.

Comment: You should edit any necessarily clarifications into the question itself; comments can be cleaned up at any time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking from experience with a mixed alignment party: a **common goal** in game, is a great way, to help ensure player co-operation. Even a mix of evil (lawful and neutral - chaotic is a no) and good. As it's within the mutual interest of both to work together for it, even if for different in-character reasons.

But if there's no at least *starting* common goal, they can split away. As seems to be the problem.

For a very broad example, of the sort of thing I mean: there is some bad NPC. He's causing a lot of trouble for innocent civilians. Thus, the two good aligned PCs have an investment in stopping them. But, this NPC is also causing problems for the more crime-orientated PCs. His activities are increasing guards, or he is an active competitor or rival to who they work with, etc. Meaning they also will have an investment in stopping him.

Thus both could work together. Despite personal differences.

Long-term, what happens during this enforced mutual co-operation can help it happen again in the future. The characters all know each other through something big and there could be character and/or plot development which helps facilitate this: but that is less set/guaranteed. As it depends on how it goes.

But, this would likely need to be something that is taken up out-of-character with the GM. Since they are the one with the power to implement something like this. Discuss potentially, if there is the possibility, of some sort of plot-hook which can force this diverging band together.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's the answer, that we're splintering because we don't have a clear quest any more.  Hopefully the DM can help us find it.  I have a feeling we've been given hints to find it but haven't managed to do so.

Comment: Chaotic Evil can work, as long as the player is willing to have random bouts of cooperation. I played a CE fighter in an evil campaign; the LE cleric and wizard tried to politic control of the group from each other, but both worried about the fighter that rolled 19 and 20 to shrug off Will saves and could out-fight the entire party. When the fighter caught on, he laughed, chugged a beer, and walked out of the meeting to get laid. He was the CE glue of that group.

Comment: After some email chat we've agreed on some shared goals, one of which (I think) will lead us on to an actual from-the-book quest, so thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

See if there is a way to achieve both goals at the same time. On the face of it, it seems incompatible.

But what is the "criminal" group really interested in?
Maybe they just want to be evil, then it's not going to work.

But probably you could be spies/agents for a righteous cause, and everyone could enjoy it.

The "criminal" elements get to act like thugs sometimes, intimidate somewhat evil people, break into stuff, maybe even rob, ahem I mean confiscate some stuff.
You can participate grudgingly seeing the necessity of it, and send a letter to get them reimbursed from the crown.

Basically you do a lot of stuff thats normally criminal/immoral, but because you are sanctioned by the crown and it's for the greater good of the realm it's OK. This even has some support in the Rulebook, one of the backgrounds is Spy.

Based on my experience of playing as a Rogue, and wanting to do Rogue stuff.

Comment: Good advice, thanks.  As it turned out, we didn't go and become thieves, and for that reason we took about a month longer to finish the adventure than we perhaps could have.